# Java webapp header nosniff not woking for js and css files

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, http-headers

I have a standard Spring MVC on tomcat.  In my web.xml file I have this:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>HTTP Header Security Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
      <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param> 
 <init-param>
  <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
  <param-value>31536000</param-value>
 </init-param>   
 <init-param>
  <param-name>hstsIncludeSubDomains</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param> 
 <init-param>
  <param-name>xssProtectionEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>blockContentTypeSniffingEnabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>HTTP Header Security Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I load any page on FF (78)  with the developer section open,  I can see in the headers that the /home page loads has the X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff as expected.  However,  all the .js and .css files that the home page loads,  does not have that in the header.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  I am using tomcat 8.5.42 and all files are being delivered via tomcat.

Comment: What exact version of Apache Tomcat are you using?

Comment: Are those .js and .css files served by Tomcat and by this web application? (It can be verified by configuring an AccessLogValve, and you can also log the value of that header).